# Redirect All Traffic in IIS 10 to another site

Tags: iis, iis-10

I am using URL rewrite to try and set up a rewrite from one site to the another site. I used URL re-write to set up this rule:

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://www.previdence.com" exactDestination="false" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SiteRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.previdence.com" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have followed a couple of tutorials on setting this up and this is what should be set. So if I type in companyname.net it will redirect to https://www.companyname.com.  If I type in https://www.companyname.net or https://companyname.net it goes to a 404.

Looking at the bindings for the old site there are bindings for PORT 443 and PORT 80 for [www.companyname.net](http://www.companyname.net).  I set the redirect in IIS for code 302, then I got URL rewrite as I explained above and I still get a 404 error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: According to your post, i can reproduce you question, you can follow Lex Li's suggestion and use failed request tracking to get detailed error information.

Comment: I ran the failed request tracking and it didn't give much.  
Site
9 

Process
13020 

Failure Reason
STATUS_CODE 

Trigger Status
301 

Final Status
301 

Time Taken
0 msec

Comment: The error you get is 404, but the status code you get in the failed request tracking is indeed 301? can you post important information in frt?

Comment: Which information would be helpful. There is a lot in the log.

Comment: You can refer to this link about how to view the gailure request log: [View the Failure Request Log File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85#step-2-view-the-failure-request-log-file).

Comment: I think I'm going to close this question.  They are moving the site to another server and will deal with the DNS entries and redirects there.  Thank you everyone for your help.  By the way there are no errors or warnings in the logs.  So I don't know what is going on.